# Can I use Google Play Services on apps installed outside the Google Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play-services, amazon-appstore

If I wanted to publish my app to the Amazon App Store for example, would Google Play Services work on that version of the app? Or does Google require apps to be downloaded from the Google Play Store exclusively to be able to connect to Google Play Services?

Comment: I don't think so... the Play Services Library connects to the Play-Services-App that is on your mobile, so I guess that you get an error that play services does not exist in the device... BUT I don't know if the "other" devices can somehow install this app so it can find it.

Answer (score 4):

I guess that if the Play Services App and it's dependencies exist on device it will work. Many ways for [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20install%20google%20play%20on%20kindle%20fire&rct=j).

On the contrary, what you are going to do with the play-service? Are you allowed to publish such an app to the Amazon? I guess that the most appropriate answer is going to be given by and the terms of their market.

According to the following guide you should change some things before uploading the **[Supported Services and Features](https://developer.amazon.com/public/support/submitting-your-app/tech-docs/02-submitting-an-android-app)** mentions that you should change:

- Google Maps `->` Use the *Amazon Maps API*.
- Google Cloud Messaging `->` Use *Amazon Device Messaging*.
- Google Play In-App Billing `->` Use the *Amazon In-App Purchasing API*.
- Google Game Play Services `->` Use *Amazon GameCircle*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Play Services on the device where it is.
Usually, where has Google Play Services installed Google Play.